# Need Help !! on understanding the error " TypeError: len() takes no keyword arguments "

Tags: python

**[1]Code:**
`print("My name is : " + len(length = input("What is your name ? \n"))+ "!!")`

**Output / Error Message:**

```
What is your name ? 
Prem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Prem Rajan/Desktop/Python_Sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    print("My name is : " + len(length = input("What is your name ? \n"))+ "!!")
TypeError: len() takes no keyword arguments
```

**Screenshot:**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVCI0.png

Comment: `len(length = input("What is your name ? \n"))` should most likely be `len(input("What is your name ? \n"))`.

Comment: What did you think `len(length = input("What is your name ? \n"))` was going to do?

Comment: Python 3.9's walrus operator will let you do `len(length := input("What is your name ? \n"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign value to a variable as a parameter to the function `len()`.
Change your code for this instead:

```py
name = input("What is your name?\n")
print("My name is: " + name + ", and the length is: " + len(name) + "!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply show the name you don't need the len function.

```
print("My name is : " + input("What is your name ? \n")+ "!!")
>> What is your name ? 
>> Sarah
>> My name is : Sarah!!
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm the question isn't so clear... what you want to do? if you want to print the length of the input you can use this

```
print("My name is : " + str(len(input("What is your name ? \n")))+ "!!")
```

else if you want to print the name you can use

```
print("My name is : " + input("What is your name ? \n")+ "!!")
```

if you want to have the input in a var you should do it in another line like this:

```
x = input("What is your name ? \n")
print("My name is : " + x +"!!")
```